# How to remove a participant from multiple events

Tags: civievent

We are using the Advanced Events extension which allows us to copy participants from one event in a series to multiple other events via the event template.  The downside of this is that, if a participant decides to no longer attend the events, we have to change the participant status to cancelled for each event individually.  Is there a way to do this in bulk?  I cannot find one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change it for the named individual via 'Find participants', select all results and then use 'Cancel registrations' from the action drop down menu (or the 'Participant status - change' option depending on your own configuration and status options)

Comment: That was very helpful.  Thank you.